# Catching logger.info output in python subprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, subprocess

**hello.py:**

```
import logging
logging.info("hello, I am a log")
```

**wrapper.py:**

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE

result = subprocess.run('python ./hello.py'.split(' '), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
print(f'returncode: {result.returncode}')
print(f'stdout: {result.stdout}')
print(f'stderr: {result.stderr}')
```

When I call `python wrapper.py`, I expected to see this output:

```
returncode: 0
stdout: INFO:root:hello, I am a log
stderr:
```

However, instead I get this output:

```
returncode: 0
stdout:
stderr:
```

And, if I replace `logging.info()` with `logger.warning()`, then I get this output:

```
returncode: 0
stdout:
stderr: WARNING:root:hello, I am a log
```

But, I have a bunch of code with `logging.info` all over the place, and I'd like to ingest it into a python subprocess. How might I do that?

---

Final notes:

- I imagine most people would prefer to call `hello.py` by doing `import hello`, but let's say that's not an option in this case.
- I am using Python 3.8.

Comment: Start with `logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)` in hello.py: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel

Comment: BTW you do not see the output when using info() because it is not printed -- if that was part of your question.

Comment: As petre points out this is unrelated to subprocess. The default logging level is warning and anything below won't appear.

Comment: @petre You're right. I didn't realize that INFO isn't printed unless you change the level. If you type that in as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, to let this have an answered, then, for potential future readers.

Add e.g. `logging.getLogger(__name__).setLevel(logging.INFO)` to `hello.py`. The default logging level is warning, as user blues points out. Therefore when you use `logging.info()` that doesn't produce any output, and this is why you do not see it.

See more at https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel

Comment: Best practice would be `logging.getLogger(__name__)` so that you're not overriding the root logger settings

Comment: Thanks, @AddisonKlinke. Not really the point of the answer, but it is probably better to have a more realistic example.